# How to add alternative HSQLDB jar as a gradle dependency?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, hsqldb, apache-calcite

Context: I am working on Apache Calcite (repo: github.com/apache/calcite) and am trying to update the HSQLDB version to 2.7.1 to address https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-41853 (the issue is being tracked here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-5938).

Because Calcite uses JDK8 I cannot simply use the normal 2.7.1 version because this only supports JDK11+. Instead I must use the alternative JAR (can be found here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.7.1/) but I am not sure how to do this in Gradle. The versions of each dependency may be found in `gradle.properties` in the repo I linked above. Does anyone know how I can use the JDK8 version of that release?

I have tried updating the dependency to `2.7.1` in `gradle.properties` as well as adding a classifier like `2.7.1:jdk8` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latest available version of HSQLDB (2.7.2) as it features new security updates. See below for a Gradle example:
https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_dependency_applications

Please report your existing Gradle code and its location for a better answer.

Update: See ttps://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html on how a version string with  qualifier is parsed.

> The "qualifier" of a version, if it exists, is the tail end of the
> version string, starting at the first non-dot separator found in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 2.7.2 works just fine as well, the main problem I am having is accessing the JDK8 jar. The file where the hsqldb version is set is here: https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/164ff0a27e243850d294908dc5cff90760d0a35a/gradle.properties#L118